# Get variable value in form in Zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Hello  every one i am new to zend framework. Is it possible to get the value of passed variable in the url in our form. For example: example.com/sth/edit/id/5
Is it possible to use get variable id in our form.

Could you please provide solution for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
// get param from request
$param = $this->getRequest()->getParam('test');

// create form
$form = new My_Form_Test();

// set value from param to testElement
$form->getElement('testElement')->setValue($param);
```